# Visual Studio Code - Deploying Aura component - Name: The Aura Component Bundle API Name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am new to VS code and this is my first aura component deployment from VS code to org.
--> connect to an org, create a project, create an aura component under aura and deploy. When I try to deploy it throws me this error. "Name: The Aura Component Bundle API Name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must be unique, begin with a letter, not include spaces, not end with an underscore, and not contain two consecutive underscores."

Not sure what is referring to? the same code .cmp and controller.js works fine when deplyed through developer console.

Comment: Does the component name violate the specification explained in the error? If not, have you got consistent naming for all the component files and in the meta.xml?

Comment: Thanks @Phil W for your time on this. Yes it look like.

Comment: It works best if you provide specific detail in your question. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to add info such as: the folder paths and file names where your LWC files are, the way the component's JavaScript class is declared, what the meta.xml looks like and the basic shape of your HTML for the component. The error sounds like a problem in naming (watch out for case differences or problems) or having the files in the wrong place.